# Using SerDes with Jetson Xavier AGX

Tags: camera, csi

I need to incorporate two types of cameras (2x connected by a long wire + 7x connected near the Xavier). For such lengths, I had to use a Serializer-Deserializer (SerDer) to make the camera wires more than 4m long.

For the camera, we are left with 3 options:

- GMSL [Gigabit Multimedia Serial Link](https://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/products/bus-systems-sbcs/gmsl-camera-operates-15m-host-remote-robotics-2018-07/) Cameras
- [FPD-Link III](http://www.ti.com/lit/slyt581) Cameras
- PoE GigE [(Power over Ethernet) Cameras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GigE_Vision), and
- [MIPI CSI2](https://www.mipi.org/specifications/camera-and-imaging) Cameras (very unusual). (Mobile Industry Processor Interface - Camera Serial Interface 2)

To avoid the cost behind the first 3, I resort to the 4th and unusual choice. I know that CSI cameras are not for such distance connections. But I saw that [Thine had solutions for that](https://www.thine.co.jp/en/application/app_details/automotive.html). I can't find a way to interface its bare-silicon (or ICs without any interfacing circuit) to the Xavier.

Is there a way to interface such (or any other) SerDes with the Xavier ?

And/Or

Is there any alternate **low-cost** solution to get my Cameras wired at such distance > 4m ?

Comment: Please explain the words you're using here when talking about something uncommon. Most everyone here will know what a serdes is, but a Jetson Xavier AGX is an entirely unfamiliar term, and I don't know what GMSL, FTDI III, GigE, MIPI, CSI, or what you mean by "bare-silicon (SMDs)".

Comment: @Hearth I have made the required edits

Answer (score 1):

1. From your list GMSL is definitely best solution.
   GMSL used several self-driving car equipment's vendors.
   E.g. Maxim Integrated has good GMSL product portfolio.
2. LVDS is also considerable solution (not only from Thine, most company provide LVDS serdes).
3. My doubt about multiplexing 9x video streams w/o glue. Tiny (or middle) FPGA would be solve this issue. If we talking about using FPGA, we also might consider to use TMDS connection to cameras (although GMSL stay still #1 in reliability for industrial application).

Comment: My top priority is cost and reliability comes second.

Comment: Ok. It seems only LVDS can meet your low cost priority.

Comment: I cannot find any such LVDS adapter/card compatible with the Xavier... hopefully owing to its short history